# JS: adding event listener to a nodelist

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I have a nodeList of li elements that I set to the var `dataList`.

```
dataList = NodeList(77) [li#result_0.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_1.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_2.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li#result_3.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_4.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_5.s-result-item.celwidget, li#result_6.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_7.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li#result_8.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_9.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_10.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li#result_11.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_12.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li, li, li#result_13.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li#result_14.s-result-item.celwidget, li, li, li, li]
```

I can log each of them successfully through a loop with:

```
for (var x=0; x < dataList.length; x++) {
    console.log(dataList[x]);
}
```

but when I try to loop through to add an eventListener, it won't work.

```
for (var x=0; x < dataList.length; x++) {
    dataList[x].addEventLister("mouseover", function() {
        console.log("test");
    });
}
```

I get back: **Uncaught TypeError: dataList[x].addEventLister is not a function at :2:7**

Comment: `addEventLister is not a function` Read that carefully, it means exactly what it says

Comment: It is said, that humans tend to fix incorrectly spelled text automatically when reading ...

Comment: doh, i see it now..thanks